# Does anyone have any information about lookback.io Android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, prototype, lookback

I am interest in find out if https://lookback.io have a SDK for android. on their website there is only for IOS.

Comment: I mean for https://lookback.io

Comment: It says `Lookback for iOS can either be installed into your app or your device.` and `Install Lookback on your Android device` so I assume there is no Android SDK

Comment: apparently they say it makes sense to just install it on the device and record your app through their app

Comment: I did sent them a email. They just replied me. They are working on the Android SDK atm

Answer (score 1):

Lookback SDK for android has been released recently.
You can find more details in [documentation on Lookback site](https://lookback.io/learn/lookback-for-your-android-app/the-lookback-android-sdk).